# Do we need [project-design]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I was recently reviewing suggested edits when a [wiki excerpt suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10485340) came up for the [project-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-design) tag. Not seeing how the tag or its description would be useful, I rejected the edit.

Looking further, I see 19 questions with the [project-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-design) tag. I feel as if this tag is too broad for Stack Overflow and should be removed as a tag.

Are project design questions on-topic?

Comment: Well, you should go through it and VTC everything off-topic. Afterwards, mention in the [SOCVR room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) that you did so and are trying to clean up [tag] (add link to this question), we will concentrate on that in the review-queue then.

Comment: I haven't looked at a tag wiki for it but the name itself suggests it's off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

I went ahead and retagged the questions, voting to close any questions that were blatantly off-topic.  I did the retagging independently from the SOCVR room, so if I made any mistakes or there are any issues please reach out to me directly.

Comment: Hope you realize that removing the tag from the questions you voted to close means no one else can find them in the close vote review queue by that tag now. Which, given the number of questions in that queue, pretty much means they'll never get closed. You should have left the tag on the close-voted questions so the rest of us could find them and help.

Comment: So I did post some of the blatantly off topic questions in the SOCVR for closing, so most, if not all of the off-topic questions were closed.  I'll definitely consider this in the future though, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @AndrewMedico why is closing those questions a better use of time than closing whatever else is in the CV queue, anyway?